# CORS: PreflightMissionAllowOriginHeader aws API gateway lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have node/express APIs running in Lambda function.
The API endpoint is `{domain}/api/user/{username}` where I pass `username` in URL itself.

**example**: to get `userA` detail, endpoint will be **xxx.com/api/user/userA**

also sending `user_id:xxx` in header.

**Hitting above endpoint using API gateway/Lambda returns the data **without any error**.**

---

**Problem occurs when I use `%` in username**.

Assume I have username as `userA%` .

Endpoint would become: **xxx.com/api/user/userA%**

Now, the problem is when I run this in my local machine with node/express/mysql api with endpoint **localhost:2000/api/user/userA%**, it returns the data.

**But** the same API using API gateway/Lambda : **xxx.com/api/user/userA%** throws

> CORS: PreflightMissionAllowOriginHeader.

I have configured some CORS policies as shown in below image but can't seem to figure out what should I configure more to allow this type of requests.[image]

Comment: Preflight means that at first, it goes to the OPTIONS end-point and then to the GET/POST/PUT. So try to add 'OPTIONS' to the Access-Control-Allow-Methods.

Comment: I tried it.  but it is giving the same result.